# create table using union all and inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I wan't to create a table using Union all and do an inner join.

***I get error :***

> Every derived table must have its own alias

P.ex

```
 create temporary table tmp_a( 
select * from(
select a, b from table1
)
union all
(
select a, b from table2
)tmp
inner join mytable on mytable.a = tmp.a);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You added `tmp` for the second table, but nothing to the first. Add for example `t1` before union all, as an alias for first table.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

you not mention the `alias` name in your query

```
create temporary table tmp_a( 
select * from(
select a, b from table1
)tmp1
union all
(
select a, b from table2
)tmp
inner join mytable on mytable.a = tmp.a);
```